# Angular 6 upgradation - Debug values are not shown in VS 2017

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, intellisense, angular6

Recently I have upgraded Angular from Angular 4 to latest version. After upgradation, VS 2017 is not showing intellisense.

Here is my packages.json file

```
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "6.1.0",
"@angular/cli": "^6.1.1",
"@angular/common": "6.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "6.1.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.0",
"@angular/core": "6.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "6.1.0",
"@angular/http": "6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "6.1.0",
"@angular/router": "6.1.0",
"@ngtools/webpack": "^6.1.1",
"@types/chai": "4.1.4",
"@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
"@types/webpack-env": "1.13.6",
"angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
"angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
"aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
"aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "5.2.0",
"bootstrap": "4.1.3",
"chai": "4.1.2",
"css": "2.2.3",
"css-loader": "1.0.0",
"es6-shim": "0.35.3",
"event-source-polyfill": "0.0.12",
"expose-loader": "0.7.5",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
"file-loader": "1.1.11",
"html-loader": "0.5.5",
"isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
"jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
"jquery": "3.3.1",
"json-loader": "0.5.7",
"karma": "2.0.5",
"karma-chai": "0.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
"karma-webpack": "3.0.0",
"popper.js": "^1.12.9",
"preboot": "6.0.0-beta.4",
"raw-loader": "0.5.1",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
"rxjs": "6.2.2",
"style-loader": "0.21.0",
"to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
"typescript": "2.9.2",
"url-loader": "1.0.1",
"webpack": "^4.16.3",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "2.22.3",
"webpack-merge": "4.1.3",
"zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "dependencies": {
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.2.0",
"ng-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
"ngx-loading": "^1.0.14",
"ngx-pagination": "^3.1.1",
"npm": "^6.2.0",
"w3-css": "^4.1.0"

  }
```

[Click link for Code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ABWV.png)

When I hover on the "url" variable, am not seeing anything, same applies to "result" as well. 
can someone suggest me if I am missing something?

Update: Click on the below image and see both in the immediate window as well as in the watch window, am not able to see the variable values.

[No value shown in immediate window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpPNr.png)

Comment: I think the angular intellisense is better when using some editors like VS code, and when you have a plugin, I use angular v6 snippet by John papa

Comment: First what kind of intellisense is not working? Within the angular html/ngml templates? or typescript files? You don't seem to have the language service in your dev dependencies and probably also not within your tsconfig. Do you have the latest TypeScript Tools for VS installed? You use 2.9.2 in your packages do you also have you installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TypeScriptTeam.typescript-292-vs2017? (can also be installed via VS 2017 installer)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, it is not related to intellisense, when I debug, and hover the mouse over the variable am not seeing any value for that variable, even in the watch window as well.

Comment: Any help on this? I am still having the same issue. I am not able to see the variable values when i hover over those in debug mode in VS 2017.